# Trying to remove a position from a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I am trying to remove an iteration in a linked list.  I need to be able to give the method an integer which is the place that the item to be removed should be.

For example if my linked list is {1, 3, 5, 7, 9} and I enter RemoveValue(2) then my new list should be {1, 5, 7, 9}.

I run the program and keep getting a segmentation fault.  I have tried looking up the answer to no avail.  I thought it might be out of bounds but I don't see how when I don't traverse beyond tail.   The RemoveValue method I am referring to.  I highlighted it down below. I listed the other cpp files I am using but not the headers, I assumed they wouldn't be needed.

linkedlist.cpp

```
#include "linked_list.hpp"
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{
    this->head = nullptr;
    this->tail = nullptr;
    this->size = 0;
}

template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::InsertAtHead(T value)
{
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(value);
    newNode->SetNext(this->head);
    this->head = newNode;
    if(this->tail == nullptr)
    {
        this->tail = newNode;
    }
    this->size++;
}

template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::Print()
{
    Node<T>* currentNode = this->head;
    while(currentNode != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << currentNode->GetValue() << std::endl;
        currentNode = currentNode->GetNext();
    }

}

template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::ReturnValue(int num){
    Node<T>* currentNode = this->head;
    int searchNum = num;
    for (int x = 0; x <= searchNum ; x++){
    if (searchNum == x)
            std::cout<<currentNode->GetValue();
       currentNode = currentNode -> GetNext();
    }
}   

template<class T>
```

> ```
> template<class T>
> void LinkedList<T>::RemovePosition(int num){
>     Node<T>* previousNode = this-> head;
>     Node<T>* currentNode = head-> GetNext();
>     int searchPosition = num - 1;
>     if ((this->head = nullptr) || (this->tail = nullptr))
>         return;
>     else {
>     for (int x = 0; x <= searchNum ; x++){
>       if (searchPosition == x){ 
>           previousNode -> SetNext(currentNode-> GetNext());
>           size--;
>           delete currentNode;
>           break;
>           }
>       currentNode = currentNode -> GetNext();
>       }
>     }   
> }
> ```

```
template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::Append(T value){
    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(value);
    if (this-> head == nullptr) {
        this-> head = newNode;
        this -> tail = newNode;
    }
        else { 
            this -> tail -> SetNext(newNode);

    }
        size++;

}

template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::InsertAt(int position, T value)
{
    if(position < 0 || position > size)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(position == 0)
    {
        InsertAtHead(value);
        return;
    }
    if(position == this->size)
    {
        //Append
    }

    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(value);
    int currentPosition = 0;
    Node<T>* currentNode = this->head;
    while(currentPosition != position - 1)
    {
        currentPosition++;
        currentNode = currentNode->GetNext();
    }
    newNode->SetNext(currentNode->GetNext());
    currentNode->SetNext(newNode);
    this->size++;   
}

template class LinkedList<int>;
```

node.cpp

```
#include "node.hpp"
#include <string>

template<typename T>
Node<T>::Node()
{
    this->value = 0;
    this->next = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
Node<T>::Node(T value)
{
    this->value = value;
    this->next = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
T Node<T>::GetValue()
{
    return this->value;
}

template<typename T>
void Node<T>::SetNext(Node* next)
{
    this->next = next;
}

template<typename T>
Node<T>* Node<T>::GetNext()
{
    return this->next;
}

template class Node<int>;
template class Node<double>;
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "node.hpp"
#include "linked_list.hpp"

int main()
{
    Node<int>* newNode = new Node<int>(12);
    Node<int>* nextNode = new Node<int>(24);
    if(12 == newNode->GetValue())
        std::cout << "GetValue passed" << std::endl;
    newNode->SetNext(nextNode);
    if(24 == newNode->GetNext()->GetValue())
        std::cout << "GetNext passed" << std::endl;
    Node<double>* doubleNode = new Node<double>(3.678);
    if((3.678 - doubleNode->GetValue() < .001) && (3.678 - doubleNode->GetValue() > -.001))
        std::cout << "Double worked" << std::endl;

    LinkedList<int>* linkedList = new LinkedList<int>();
    linkedList->InsertAtHead(5);
    linkedList->InsertAtHead(3);
    linkedList->InsertAtHead(1);
    linkedList->Append(8);
    linkedList->Print();
    linkedList->RemovePosition(3);
    linkedList->InsertAt(2, 4);
    linkedList->Print();
    linkedList->ReturnValue(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems (from the comments on a now deleted answer), that the RemoveValue method, despite it's name, is actually removing a node at a given position. I would update the question (and rename the method) to make that clear.

Comment: @john I changed the title, cleaned it up, and took the last advice I received and added guards for null values.  Thank you.

Comment: `=` is assignment, not equality comparison.

Comment: What does RemoveValue(1) should do ? If it should remove the head, you have a probleme. RemoveValue(1) remove the Next element after head. And If RemoveValue(0) should remove head, you are in infinite loop for (x=0; x<-1; ++x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few errors in your code, the main one is that you don't update the value of `previousNode`. You set it to `head` at the beginning of your method and then never touch it again.

Here's how I might do it (including giving everything sensible names)

```
template<class T>
void LinkedList<T>::RemoveAt(int pos) {
    Node<T>* prev = nullptr;
    Node<T>* curr = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < pos && curr != nullptr; ++i) {
        prev = curr;            // set prev to old value of current
        curr = curr->GetNext(); // and move current forward
    }
    if (curr == nullptr) { // nothing to delete?
        return;            // then do nothing
    }
    else if (prev == null) {    // no previous pointer?
        head = curr->GetNext(); // then remove the head
    }
    else {
        prev->SetNext(curr->GetNext());
    }
    if (tail == curr) // are we deleteing the tail?
        tail = prev;  // then update
    delete curr;
}
```

Completely untested code, so I'm not guaranteeing no errors. But the important point is that I update the `prev` variable in my loop.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't even notice that I hadn't updated the previous node.  I kept looking at it knowing it was there, but I didn't think about the fact that I didn't update it.